# Paypal Scheduled Payment

Tags: javascript, vb.net, paypal, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am implementing paypal payment into my vb.net project using javascript payment system.

I want to schedule payment.
For example- I want to enable user to schedule payment in future.

How can i do this?

Please suggest.

Comment: Is this an MVC website or ASP.NET? What javascript payment system are you using?

Comment: ASP.NET website